# how do I match a url in php using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the value of query `v` in the following regex:

```
http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/videos\/video.php\?.*v=([a-z0-9-_]+)
```

A sample url:

```
http://www.domain.com/videos/video.php?v=9Gu0sd2dmm91B9b1
```

The url is always www and I'm only trying to match the `v` value. Does anyone know what's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget the capital letters

```
http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/videos\/video.php\?.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)
```

Comment: a case-insensitive modifier would also work (and might be better, as the domain could be mixed case too)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. It's way easier to use:

```
$url_components = parse_url("http://www.domain.com/videos/video.php?v=9Gu0sd2dmm91B9b1");

echo $url_components['query'];
```

From there I think you can do the rest and slice off the first couple of letters. Once you do that you're left with only the stuff after `v=`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the period '.' in video.php. I also use a different delimiter if I am escaping paths/URL's - like this:

```
preg_match( "#http://www\.domain\.code/videos/video\.php\?.*v=([^&]*)#", $url, $matches );
```

If the v= is in the middle of the query string,

```
v=([^&]*)
```

.. will match everything up to another & symbol, just in case characters other than alphas and _,- end up in there for some reason.